# is there any way to check ajax readystatechange using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a fully ajax based website, uptil now i was using my ajax function to send request but i am planning to switch to jquery,
In my state change function i am checking state of xmlRequest, but in jquery ihaven't seen such function , it has only callback function which gets called when readyState changes to 'complete', is there any way to observe intermediate states of request i.e 1,2,3,4

please provide a example

Comment: Do you really need this? Or better, can you explain why you need this?

Comment: @Yoshi i need to show a loader animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this url: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
and this url for the events: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

You can do something like:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url : "/url.html",
                data : {
                    id: 12,
                    name : "Niels",
                    age : 22
                },
                beforesend : function(){
                    // Show loader here
                    $(".loader").show();
                },
                ajaxSend : function(){

                },
                complete : function(){
                    // Hide loader here
                    $(".loader").hide();
                }
            });
```

Quote from jQuery ajax url:

> No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since success, error, complete and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements.

Comment: actually i need to put a loader which needs shows when data is loaded,so where should i put it

Comment: The data you want to send. Ill put an example.

Comment: niels,ok the loader is showing but after the data is fully loaded. i want to show loader when page is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events.

They're typically used to show spinner elements for the duration of AJAX requests.